# Enable google spreadsheet API

Tags: permissions, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to do an app that requires google spreadsheet API, however it looks like I can't enable it from the console. Therefore, I can't ask for the permissions to the documents.
I know that it is possible, because I found this playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground which asks for permissions for Spreadsheet API, but I just don't know how they did it.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use OAuth2 with the `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` permission scope. If you would like to create new spreadsheet file in the user's Drive, then you also need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets) for more on the Spreadsheet API and [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) for Drive.

Comment: This is a scope name, not a real URL. Read here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize .